# Why react-router setRouteLeaveHook broke index link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**Problem:** If i add router.setRouteLeaveHook() or router.listenBefore() to my component it will break logo homepage Link to path="/"

**Details:**
I want to create section leave confirm. Here is my component code. (withRouter wrapped)

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.routerWillLeave);
},

routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
}
```

My problem is when i click on Link or IndexLink (path='/') and confirm transition i got error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http:' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://mydomain.dev' and URL 'http://mydomain.dev/user/services'.
```

**Debug:** Found that in lib/createBrowserHistory.js is this function call

```
window.history.pushState(historyState, null, path);
```

where path is // instead of expected /. (location object has base '/' and path '/')

**Versions:** react@15.4.1, react-router@2.8.1, history@2.1.2

Comment: Looks like related to https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2956. Do you have the base tag in your HTML? Also try using relative path as a temporary workaround `<Link to path="./" />`

Comment: I don't have base tag. I set base over `useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: config.BASE_NAME
});`. When i change link to relative path `<Link to="./" />` browser url looks ok, but react-router will not match it as Index route and i have to add `<Route component={Landing} path="./"/>`

Comment: Found that config.BASE_NAME="/". When i remove that slash it works. Thank you @EvanSebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Router basename was wrong. "/" instead of "".